# Typescript Error Cannot find name 'require'. IONIC 3

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic3

Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'require'.
C:/Users/me/project/src/pages/home/home.ts
            // require the Twilio module and create a REST client

const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

Ionic Framework: 3.3.0

Ionic App Scripts: 1.3.7

Angular Core: 4.1.2

Angular Compiler CLI: 4.1.2

Node: 6.10.3

OS Platform: Windows 10

Navigator Platform: Win32

User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;

[ts code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPaCd.png)

CODE inside home.ts:

TOP

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseProvider } from './../../providers/firebase/firebase';
import { FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BarcodeScanner ,BarcodeScannerOptions } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
import { Request } from '@angular/http';


@Component({
selector: 'home',
templateUrl: 'home.html',
})
```

//ALERT FUNCTION

```
scanAlert(){
    this.options = {
      showFlipCameraButton : true,
      formats : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", 
      prompt : "SCAN QR CODE "
    }
    this.barcodeScanner.scan(this.options).then((barcodeData) => {
        console.log(barcodeData);
        this.pinText = barcodeData.text;
        const uid = this.pinText;
        this.firebaseProvider.afd.database.ref('pins')
        .orderByChild('QRCODE')
        .equalTo(uid)
        .limitToFirst(1)
        .once('value', snap => {
            let key = Object.keys(snap.val())[0]; // KEY VALUE 
            let user = snap.child(key).val(); // the whole user object
            this.message = 'Parameters to send to twilio' + user.phone + 
                  'regarding'+user.message;

            const accountSid = 'myacctid';
            const authToken = 'mytoken';

            // require the Twilio module and create a REST client
            const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

            client.messages
            .create({
                to: '+142mynumber  ',
                from: '+mysms trial#',
                body: 'TEST Alert Message !',
  })
  .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
```

I followed these steps

install require --save

and

npm install @types/node --save-dev

My issue is that the message does not get sent.

if i add

```
declare var require: any
```

the error goes away, but twilio never gets the request to send the message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZEsP.png)

I cannot find any tutorials for Ionic3 or Angular and twilio to send an sms
I have not even passed the parameters, I copied the

I also tried this

```
    var twilio = require('twilio');//Make sure to npm install @types/node
    var accountSid = 'myacctid'; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
    var authToken = 'myauthtoken';   // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console


    var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken);

    client.messages.create({
        body: 'ALERT! Someone has scanned the Alert Code for ',
        to: '+myphone'  ,// Text this number
        from: '+myTwilioTrial#' // From a valid Twilio number
    })
    .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
```

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
"types": [
    "node"
],
"typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
]
```

in the **tsconfig.json** file

Comment: Just an FYI for others, you need to put this under `compilerOptions`.

Answer (score 2):

> @types/node

`@types` work best if you have `module: node` in your `tsconfig.json`.

## More

- Potential setup https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: npm install @types/node --save-dev

Comment: I did this in my project here is my tsconfig.json