# How can I use require creditcard in Ionic 3

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, node-modules

How do I use the node module [creditcard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/creditcards) with Ionic 3?

The examples of implementation are:

```
var Card = require('creditcards/card')
var card = Card([visa])
card.isValid('4242424242424242')
// => true

var expiration = require('creditcards/expiration')
expiration.isPast(10, 2010)
// => true
```

But with Ionic 3 I get the error `Cannot find name 'require'.` I found similar issue with `lodash` in ionic here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/8274

I tried posted solutions and none seemed to work.

First I tried adding `import card from 'creditcards/card';`
Here is the ionic code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import card from 'creditcards/card';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'creditcard.html'
})
export class CreditcardPage {
  creditContent: string;
  constructor() {
    this.creditContent = card.isValid(`42424242424242`);
  }
}
```

I get the error `ReferenceError: card is not defined`.

I tried `import 'creditcards/card';`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'creditcards/card';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'creditcard.html'
})
export class CreditcardPage {
  creditContent: string;
  constructor() {
    this.creditContent = card.isValid(`42424242424242`);
  }
}
```

I get the error  `Uncaught ReferenceError: Card is not defined`

There is also a post in SO: [Typescript Error Cannot find name 'require'. IONIC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44424834/typescript-error-cannot-find-name-require-ionic-3). This does not provide relevant information as it is specific to `@types/node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is in your tsconfig file. You should include the 'types:[node]'